# Parse webpage code with extension

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-chrome-extension

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "0.1",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
     "https://opskins.com/*"
   ],
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "content.js"]


    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }

}
```

content.js:

```
var sticker = document.body.querySelector('.sticker');

if (sticker) {
var stickerTitle = sticker.getAttribute('title');
}
console.log(stickerTitle)
```

https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_browse&app=730_2
works with the page. But the console response is `undefined`.

That's what I need:

[image: that's what I need]

Comment: Many pages add elements dynamically after the page has reported DOMContentLoaded event. Try using setTimeout or MutationObserver.

Comment: i did  through array of querySelectorAll